# SQL: Find top n in groupby data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id  | name   | surname | city|
-------------------------------
'1', 'mohit', 'garg', 'delhi'
'2', 'mohit', 'gupta', 'delhi'
'3', 'ankita', 'gupta', 'jaipur'
'4', 'ankita', 'garg', 'jaipur'
'5', 'vivek', 'garg', 'delhi'
```

I am looking for a query that returns (id,city) grouped by city, with at most two (id) per city, but without using nested queries.

**Expected output**:

```
'1', 'delhi'
'2', 'delhi'
'3', 'jaipur'
'4', 'jaipur'
```

Comment: you want to group by city and surname order by id?

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use nested queries? That seems like by far the easiest solution to this problem.

Comment: Is it nesting or correlation that you are trying to avoid?  A well written subquery is neither expensive nor a bad thing.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave : I am defining SQL-like language for my data platform using Antlr based parser. One of the use-case demands this functionality. At the moment my language is small subset of SQL, without nesting, with some additional application-specific vocabulary. Thats why I was exploring easier ways of achieving this. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the only way without subqueries is to use a trick with `substring_index()` and `group_concat()`:

```
select city, substring_index(group_concat(id), ',', 2)
from t
group by city;
```

This puts the ids in a comma-delimited list, rather than in separate rows.  Also, you have to be careful about the size of the intermediate results.

Of course, the accepted practice would use either a subquery in the `where` clause or a subquery using variables.

EDIT:

Here is a method for getting two ids per city without listing the cities:

```
select city, min(id) as id
from t
group by city
union
select city, max(id)
from t
group by city;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, although using a subquery will probably be clearer and might be faster. Here's a method using the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.city
FROM
    My_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON T2.city = T1.city AND T2.id <= T1.id
GROUP BY
    T1.id,
    T1.city
HAVING
    COUNT(*) <= 2
```

You're effectively finding all rows in T1 where the number of rows with the same name and a lower id is <= 2, which means that it must be one of the top two rows by id.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
create table
#test (id int, name varchar(10), name2 varchar(10),place varchar(10))


insert into #test
select
'1', 'mohit', 'garg', 'delhi'
union
select
'2', 'mohit', 'gupta', 'delhi'
union
select
'3', 'ankita', 'gupta', 'jaipur'
union
select
'4', 'ankita', 'garg', 'jaipur'
union
select
'5', 'vivek', 'garg', 'delhi'



with data
as
(
select    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY place ORDER BY id) RN,id,name,name2,place
from #test
),
data1
as(
select id, place
from data
where rn <=2
)

select *from  data1
```

Comment: MySQL and `ROW_NUMBER()` and `temp table`? Looks like SQL Server

Comment: This query would also return cities that only appear once.